# InsertImage(url,x,y) doesn't work with Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have saved an image in my Google Drive, and I want my script to insert that image into a spreadsheet. But when I call [InsertImage(url x,x)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#insertImage%28String,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29) with Google Drive URL of the photo, I get an error:

```
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
```

How can I insert this image into the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use the URL of an image on Google Drive with InsertImage.

There is an outstanding issue for this, which has been a feature request for several years. Star it to receive updates.

> [Issue 145](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=145): insertImage() doesn't work with images stored on google documents

You will need to have your image hosted on an external server with stable URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use the Advanced Drive SDK to get whatever metadata of the [File object](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) you need, including, for example, the selfLink or the thumbnailLink.

I wrote a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/sjsyrek/de2c4b3506287cc87760) to retrieve thumbnail image URLs from image files we keep stored on Google Drive and automatically insert them as image formulas into a spreadsheet according to a filename pattern based on part numbers from the sheet.

Once you have the URL, you can build an =IMAGE(url) formula with it to insert the image directly into a cell, which may be more useful to you, or you can use the [insertImage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertImage(String,Integer,Integer)) function to insert the image into the document as one of those floating overlay things. You can use this same method to fetch a binary blob, if you'd rather insert the image data itself and not just an URL reference to it, but that won't work for formulas (only the overlays using the [insertImage() function, blob version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertImage(Blob,Integer,Integer))). Here's an example from [Google Issue 4344](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4344) of how to use UrlFetchApp to get an image thumbnail from a file:

```
function getThumbnail(fileId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(file.thumbnailLink).getBlob();
}
```

If you only want the link, just leave off the getBlob() function. If you want the full size image, try the selfLink property instead. If you want more detail, see my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/sjsyrek/de2c4b3506287cc87760).

This is definitely a workaround, so I don't know if it will continue to work or if Google will finally provide a reasonable implementation in the future. Please note, however, that you need to activate the Drive SDK in your script file under Resources : Advanced Google services and also in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com). If it doesn't work, make sure the project ID in the Script project matches the one associated with the project in the console. I had to actually create a new project in the console and reset the ID to match in the script.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's very easy to do. Make a public folder on Google drive place images there and then use http://googledrive.com/folders_id/image_name.jpg to get it. Tell me if it doesn't work

Comment: Does not work for enterprise Google Apps users, in domains not allowed to set public visibility.

Comment: Publishing web sites from Google Drive was deprecated.

Comment: yeah it's almost impossible right now to do using just basic google tools